# Backref also lists and links to citations in listoffigure/listoftables

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, back-referencing

I sometimes use `\cite` in the `figure` or `table` environment and use backref to be able to link to citations from the bibliography.

If I include a list of figures or list of tables the citation is repeated and the corresponding pagenumber is listed in the bibliography.

How can I prevent the count of the second citation, so that only the first one in the main text appears in the bibliography?

**MWE**:

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
\ifcase #1 %
Not cited.%
\or
Cited on page #2.%
\else
Cited on pages #2.%
\fi
}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\begin{figure}
\caption{Lorem ipsum \cite{One}.}
\end{figure}

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{bib}
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

bib.bib:

```
@Article{One,
title={This},
author={Me},
year=2013,
journal={My journal},
volume=1
}
```

Compile 3-4 times and both locations will show up in the bibliography.

Comment: You could use the optional argument (whose text in the ToC): `\caption[Lorem ipsum]{Lorem ipsum \cite{One}.}` (in the LoF and LoT it doesn't make much sense to have a citation, after all).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? The optional argument is the caption text?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake in my previous comment. The optional argument will be used in the list of figures; the main argument will be used in the actual figure caption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 2012/07/24 v1.37 package `backref` provides options `enable` and `disable` that can here be used to change the recording of the back references:

```
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}[2012/07/24]
...
\backrefsetup{disable}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\backrefsetup{enable}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know of this option. Really useful.

Comment: If I put this before `\begin{document}` I get an error: "LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}". If I put it after `\begin{...` I get another instance of LoF and LoT and warnings about duplicate uses of destination identifiers...

Comment: Also the current documentation of backref doesn't mention this.

Comment: @BandGap The documentation [`backref.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/backref.pdf) does mention options `enable` and `disable` in section "2.1.3 Other options".

Comment: @BandGap What's the difficulty putting `\backrefsetup{disable}` and `\backrefsetup{enable}` around your `\listoffigures`?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I misinterpreted the example in the docs. Thanks for pointing that out. It's not difficult to put anything around anything. It's that your example doesn't point out where this should be put. I didn't interpret the ellipses as you had intended :)